# Monogame Breakout: having trouble with adding abilities like longer paddle or more balls

Tags: if-statement, random, switch-statement, monogame, breakout

I'm gonna add some abilities to random blocks, u know that drops down when you hit a random block. Like you get 2 balls or bigger paddle or slower ball speed.

I need help with writing the for loop and if-statement that can add some abilities to my block levels. Like 1 random ability on level 1 and so on. So when you hit 1 random block of like 20 blocks, that has my ability. It would drop down to the paddle like the original breakout game.

I was thinking of a switch, if one random block with ability is hit and using that switch and randomize it.

```
    void PowerUp()
    {
        powerups.Add(abilityballs_rect);
        powerups.Add(abilitylong_rect);
        powerups.Add(abilityslow_rect);
    }
```

-

```
    List<Rectangle> block = new List<Rectangle>();
    List<Rectangle> block2 = new List<Rectangle>();
    List<Rectangle> block3 = new List<Rectangle>();
    List<Rectangle> block4 = new List<Rectangle>();
    List<Rectangle> block5 = new List<Rectangle>();
    List<Rectangle> block6 = new List<Rectangle>();

    List<Rectangle> powerups = new List<Rectangle>();
```

-

```
            if (level == 1)
            {
                if (block.Count == 14 && block2.Count == 14)
                {
                    spriteBatch.DrawString(spritefont2, "LEVEL " + level, new Vector2(252, 400), Color.White);
                }

                foreach (Rectangle g in block)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(block_texture, g, Color.LimeGreen);
                }
                foreach (Rectangle r in block2)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(block_texture, r, Color.IndianRed);
                }
            }

            else if (level == 2)
            {
                if (block3.Count == 18 && block4.Count == 27)
                {
                    spriteBatch.DrawString(spritefont2, "LEVEL " + level, new Vector2(246, 400), Color.White);
                }

                foreach (Rectangle b in block3)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(block_texture, b, Color.CornflowerBlue);
                }
                foreach (Rectangle y in block4)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(block_texture, y, Color.Yellow);
                }
            }

            else if (level == 3)
            {
                if (block5.Count == 36 && block6.Count == 18)
                {
                    spriteBatch.DrawString(spritefont2, "LEVEL " + level, new Vector2(246, 400), Color.White);
                }

                foreach (Rectangle o in block5)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(block_texture, o, Color.Orange);
                }
                foreach (Rectangle p in block6)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(block_texture, p, Color.HotPink);
                }
            }
```

-

```
    void AddBlocks()
    {
        //LEVEL 1
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int f = 1; f < 8; f++)
            {
                block.Add(new Rectangle((f * 63) + 94, (i * 40) + 60, block_texture.Width, block_texture.Height));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int g = 1; g < 8; g++)
            {
                block2.Add(new Rectangle((g * 63) + 94, (i * 40) + 40, block_texture.Width, block_texture.Height));
            }
        }

        //LEVEL 2
        for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++)
            {
                block3.Add(new Rectangle((j * 63) + 34, (i * 200) - 60, block_texture.Width, block_texture.Height));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k < 4; k++)
            {
                block4.Add(new Rectangle((k * 103) + 143, (i * 20) + 140, block_texture.Width, block_texture.Height));
            }
        }

        //LEVEL 3
        for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < 7; j++)
            {
                block5.Add(new Rectangle((j * 63) + 127, (i * 20) + 190, block_texture.Width, block_texture.Height));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 1; k < 3; k++)
            {
                block6.Add(new Rectangle((k * 443) - 317, (i * 20) + 160, block_texture.Width, block_texture.Height));
            }
        }
    }
```

-

```
    void DeleteBlocks()
    {
        if (level == 1)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < block.Count; j++)
            {
                if (ball_rect.Intersects(block[j]))
                {
                    ball_speed.Y *= -1;
                    points += 1;
                    block.RemoveAt(j);
                    if (points > highscore)
                    {
                        highscore = points;
                    }
                }
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < block2.Count; k++)
            {
                if (ball_rect.Intersects(block2[k]))
                {
                    ball_speed.Y *= -1;
                    points += 1;
                    block2.RemoveAt(k);
                    if (points > highscore)
                    {
                        highscore = points;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (block.Count == 0 && block2.Count == 0)
            {
                level++;
                StartValueBallPaddle();
                Start = false;
            }
        }

        else if (level == 2)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < block3.Count; l++)
            {
                if (ball_rect.Intersects(block3[l]))
                {
                    ball_speed.Y *= -1;
                    points += 1;
                    block3.RemoveAt(l);
                    if (points > highscore)
                    {
                        highscore = points;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int m = 0; m < block4.Count; m++)
            {
                if (ball_rect.Intersects(block4[m]))
                {
                    ball_speed.Y *= -1;
                    points += 1;
                    block4.RemoveAt(m);
                    if (points > highscore)
                    {
                        highscore = points;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (block3.Count == 0 && block4.Count == 0)
            {
                level++;
                StartValueBallPaddle();
                Start = false;
            }
        }

        else if (level == 3)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < block5.Count; n++)
            {
                if (ball_rect.Intersects(block5[n]))
                {
                    ball_speed.Y *= -1;
                    points += 1;
                    block5.RemoveAt(n);
                    if (points > highscore)
                    {
                        highscore = points;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int o = 0; o < block6.Count; o++)
            {
                if (ball_rect.Intersects(block6[o]))
                {
                    ball_speed.Y *= -1;
                    points += 1;
                    block6.RemoveAt(o);
                    if (points > highscore)
                    {
                        highscore = points;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to ask with your post.  Are you having problems getting your code to do something?  Do you want someone to check your code for something?  You need to rephrase your post's title into a clearer question.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I think it's clearer now. Sorry about my english :P

Answer (score 0):

You might want to encapsulate your block data into a class, containing the color, the position and powerup of the block.
You could have a method inside that would be called "AddPowerup()" or something, this method will be used to add a random (or specific) powerup to the block. You'll maybe need a getter for your powerup.
Now in your game, you would hold all the blocks of a level inside a list, or a 2d array, or any collection that suits you
Then, to apply powerup to random blocks in the level, you could do something like this (mostly pseudo code, so not tested) :

```
List<Block> blockList = CreateBlockLevel(1);
int randomIndex = new Random().Next(blockList.Length-1);
blockList[randomIndex].AddPowerup();
```

If you want to apply a powerup to multiple blocks, you can put that in a for-loop, but then you might want to check if the block has already a powerup or not.